# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

Tags: javascript, json, xml

estoy haciendo un programa de ARjs junto con A-frame y para obtener los datos de un web service hice un json con el codigo QR que quiero leer y la URL donde ir a buscar datos pero luego de que cargue el json y lo muestre me manda el error

`XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: file:///C:/Users/win7/Desktop/arConfig/mostrar.json
Line Number 1, Column 1:`

pero el json esta bien construido

```
{
  "B001": {
    "texto":{
      "state":{
        "TRUE":"abierto",
        "FALSE":"cerrado"
      },
      "tipo":"bool",
      "mostrar":"imagen"
    },
    "datos":"http://172.168.0.97:5000/api/shift/equipment/213"
  },
  "B002": {
    "texto":{
      "tipo":"int",
      "mostrar":"porcentaje"
    },
    "datos":"https://172.168.0.64:8000/AR?tag=Lectura.Level"
  }
}
```

La parte del codigo que lee el json es la siguiente

```
var machine = QR;
$.getJSON('mostrar.json',function(modificador){
    console.log(modificador);
    $.getJSON(modificador[machine].datos,function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

y el mensaje de error me salta luego del primer console.log(modificador);

Comment: El error es por intentar pasar algo a XML y en ese trozo de código no hay nada relacionado o no lo veo. Por lo que tendrás que buscar en algún otro lado.

Comment: pero me dice que el problema esta en "mostrar.json" a pesar de que lo puede leer al principio. El error me salta luego del console.log(modificador) por lo que no deberia darme ningun error ahi ya que ya lo leyo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La primera consulta que haces esta bien hecha y te retorna el `json` del archivo `mostrar.json`.

El error viene cuando haces una segunda petición `$.getJSON` al archivo que recuperas del `json` en el apartado de `datos`.

Es decir, haces una petición a `http://172.168.0.97:5000/api/shift/equipment/213` (por ejemplo) y este archivo no es un `.json`.

Además cabe la posibilidad de que ese archivo contenga un archivo `XML` y tu lo estás trayendo como `json`. De ahí podría tener sentido el error que te da.